# How to know what schemata are available to me in my session?

Tags: oracle, plsql

When I login as `MY_NAME`, `MY_NAME` would be my CURRENT SCHEMA (which I could change with SET CURRENT SCHEMA statement).

`SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS` would show all objects from 'all schema' that are available to me. But how can I find what schemata are available to me and in what order, something like the equivalent of PATH in a file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concept of schemas ('schemata') "being available".  A schema is really nothing but the set of objects that belong to a given owner.  The only thing that is 'available' are the individual objects.  And even at the object level, there is no concept of 'order' in which they would be available.  To resolve a given unqualified object name:

Managing Object Name Resolution

Object names referenced in SQL statements can consist of several pieces, separated by periods. The following describes how the database resolves an object name.

```
Oracle Database attempts to qualify the first piece of the name referenced in the SQL statement. For example, in scott.emp, scott is the first piece. If there is only one piece, the one piece is considered the first piece.

    In the current schema, the database searches for an object whose name matches the first piece of the object name. If it does not find such an object, it continues with step b.

    The database searches for a public synonym that matches the first piece of the name. If it does not find one, it continues with step c.

    The database searches for a schema whose name matches the first piece of the object name. If it finds one, it returns to step b, now using the second piece of the name as the object to find in the qualified schema. If the second piece does not correspond to an object in the previously qualified schema or there is not a second piece, the database returns an error.

If no schema is found in step c, the object cannot be qualified and the database returns an error.
```

(https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general008.htm#ADMIN11561)

If you want to see what schemas have objects that may be referenced by the current user you could:

```
select distinct owner
from all_objects
order by owner;
```

Comment: The schemata 'available' in my question meant the schemata searched for an unqualified object. If there is an EMP table in every schema, and I run SELECT * FROM EMP, which schema the EMP table gets picked from? I could probably get that search order by creating EMP table in all schema with different data and repeating the query each time dropping the table that got picked in the previous round. The 3rd item in the cited reference 'database searches for a schema whose name matches...' is not detailing on the search order.

Comment: There is no concept of a 'search order path through multiple schemas'.  The search order is 'current scheama', then 'public synonyms'.  Full stop.

Comment: In DB2, a schema is called Library, and a session has a list of libraries set in a particular order. An unqualified name points to the first available object in the library list [link] (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rbam6/ulibl.htm). By changing the library list/order you can have same script run against different objects, like TEST vs PRODUCTION. How is this done in Oracle?

Comment: alter session set current_schema='nextschema'. see  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general009.htm#ADMIN02101

Comment: So, SET CURRENT_SCHEMA, plus CREATE SYNONYM if needed, is the way to access different sets of tables and other objects. Thanks, accepting your answer.